# Create and initialize an object in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create and initialize an object in one shot. so instead of doing this

```
var a = function(){};

a.prototype.blah = function(){return "blah"};

var b  = new a();
```

I would like to use this.

```
var a = function(){
    return new function init() {
      this.extend = init.prototype;
      this.creator = "Levi";
      this.create = function(){
          return new init();
      }
      // other stuff
    };
  }();

  a.extend.blah = function(){return "blah";};
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm specifically unsure about using `return new function` in my code. Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify I would like to use this as a sort of wrapper around the objects prototype I do not want to use object literals like this`var a = {extend: "",creator: "Levi"}`.

Comment: I would be concerned about it too: `(new function x () { return 1 })()` returns in a TypeError as `function (..) {..}` construct creates a function *without* the use of `new`. The `new` there is actually invoked on the function object itself (it parsed as `return new (function ..)`). Is that *really* desired?

Comment: I actually do want return an instance of `a`

Comment: It's not "an instance of a", it's "an instance created from an anonymous constructor [function] that is then bound a". This is why I question it - it's a confusing way to set it up :) Note that since it is an *instance* already, there is not really a shown reason to avoid one-off properties.

Comment: @pst do you mind elaborating a little bit more on what you mean by  "an instance created from an anonymous constructor". Thanks!

Comment: The body of the IIFE is parsed as `return new (function ..)`, where `function ..` represents an anonymous constructor. It is semantically equivalent to: `function init () { .. }; return new init()`

Comment: Oh now I get what your saying.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative can be:

```
var a = (function(){

  var A = function() {
    this.creator = "Levi";
  }

  A.prototype.blah = function() {
    return "blah"
  };

  return new A;

})();
```

This may be useful for one-shot objects, `A`.